# Dynamics crm online 2016 subgrid

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016, subgrid

In the Contact form, I have a subgrid that shows the opportunities for the current Contact. So I selected "Only related records", the opportunity entity, and "All opportunities" as the defauld view.
The problem is that in this way I only see the active opportunities. Is there a way to make the subgrid also show the closed/lost opportunities?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the filter criteria of the view, it filters records by status of "Open". Either remove that filter or even better create a new view with no filters and use it for the subgrid.

[image]